# How to over come this problem in Flutter where i can in image but as a file and then assign image to on of my imagecontainer?

Tags: flutter

```
Future getImage(bool isAvatar) async {
    var result = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (isAvatar) {
        avatarImageFile = result as File;
      } else {
        backgroundImageFile = result as File;
      }
    });
```

I have used this code and it runs but when I select the file the code gives me error saying that cant set as a file.

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `getImage` method is not `File`.
Try this:

```
Future getImage(bool isAvatar) async {
    var result = await ImagePicker().getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      if (isAvatar) {
        avatarImageFile = File(result.path);
      } else {
        backgroundImageFile = File(result.path);
      }
    });
```

Comment: @Tahir if the answer helped you, please accept my answer by click on the check button under the down vote button.